# Styling <li> elements to expand to the full height of the nav background

Tags: html, css, html-lists, nav

I am trying to build a Nav that has a :hover effect.  When I hover, the hover effect will not expand to fill the entire background of the nav.  I have tried manipulating it with margin and padding, but to no avail.

Here is the CSS:

```css
div#nav {
    background-image: url("images/navback.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 580px;
    height: 85px;
    margin-left: 100px;
}

ul#navlist {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: 'OpenSansCondensedBold', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 40px;
}

ul#navlist li{
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 18px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

ul#navlist li:hover {
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 10px #ffffff;
    cursor: pointer;
}

a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #717171;
}
```

I'm a little stumped, any help is appreciated!

Here is the Markup:

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul id="navlist">
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Buy Art</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Make Money</a></li>
        <li><a href="">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Markup added, sorry, code brain going on.

Comment: Could you modify [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/u37Yv/1/), with the URLs of the actual images? Then we have something to work with to see what's going on and what's not happening.

Answer (score 1):

to style an element to full height of the parent-element you simply add:

```
height: 100%;
```

I'm not sure, but it might be you also have to add to that selector

```
display: inline-block;
```